# Domain mapping issues

Tags: web-hosting, multiple-domains, cname

I have two domain names - `.com` & `.co.uk` bought with 123-reg and just one student Windows hosting pack associated with the `.co.uk` domain.

The `.com` domain is the main one which people would be trying to access, so I just mapped the domain to the hosting this morning. The problem is that I would really like it to be functional by tomorrow morning and the usual waiting time is 24-48 hours.

Is there point in stopping the process and trying with forward it with CNAME record instead, does it take less time? (I can just go back and do proper domain mapping during the weekend)

Also, is there a possible way to check whether the domain mapping has been done correctly before these 24-48 hours? From some computers I get 404 Error on homepage.

Answer (score 1):

Propagation time varies, generally its between 1-48 hours but can take longer depending on the domain type.

The `.com` and `.co.uk` domains are very popular and *may* update these faster than say a `.biz`.

*You can take a look at name servers/dns changes using these various online tools:*

- [What's my DNS](http://www.whatsmydns.net/)
- [Pingdom DNS Check](http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/)
- [DNS Report](http://www.dnsstuff.com/)
- [MXTool Box](http://mxtoolbox.com/)

Now 'What's my DNS' tends to be the best because it doesn't just check one server it checks many. If you find the majority of servers are updated then it could be that your ISP/Router/OS needs updating/flushing. You can do a [nslookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup) on your computer to see whats going on, but first you should ensure you flush your DNS. Some browsers cache this too, and even routers.

In Windows you can do `ipconfig /flushdns` and rebooting a router normally resets any caching, with browsers there's many DNS flushes such as Firefox, simply type in Google Firefox DNS Flush Plugin and your find lots...